# Long running script error in ie and chrome crashes everytime the specific script is run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was modifying  jquery clockpick plugin for my own use. but i ran into error. Every time i load the followng script my browser crashes

when the if condition is true.
Particularly when I give varable m inside if loop some value.

What am i doing wrong? below is the code..thanks for help

```
for (var m = 0; m < 60; m = m + n) {
    /*if this condition is true my browser crashes else it runs smoothly*/
    if (settings.absolutestarthour != null && realhours <= settings.absolutestarthour.split(':')[0]) {
        excludeuntilhour = settings.absolutestarthour;
        excludeuntilhour = excludeuntilhour.split(":");
        m = n * ((Math.floor(parseInt(excludeuntilhour[1]) / n)) + 1);
        /*h=parseInt(excludeuntilhour[0]);*/
        console.log('no error');
    }
    $md = jQuery("<div class='CP_minute' id='" + realhours + "_" + m + "'>" + displayhours + ":" + ((m < 10) ? "0" : "") +
        m + tt + "</div>");
    if (!v) {
        $md.css("float", "left");
        if (settings.minutedivisions > 6 && counter == settings.minutedivisions / 2 + 1) {
            // long horizontal, kick in extra row after half
            $mc.append("<div style='clear:left' />");
        }
    }
    $mc.append($md);
    binder($md);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: `split()` returns an array of strings.

Comment: Did you check the error console to see what error was reported?

Comment: You are also changing `m` inside the loop that is based on `m`. You should probably log the value of m each iteration to see what's unexpected. I would also use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: i cannot view anything it just freezes everything, i once got long running script error in ie.

Comment: thanks Using the while loop helped